# Track down what's disabling the Magento cache

Tags: cache, full-page-cache

As it often happens, you log into your Magento Back-end and you see that a cache has been disabled.
Is there a way to track what is disabling the cache so that we can fix the problem - if there is one?

Comment: It says that cache block was invalidated. It happens when someone buys a product, qty is decreased.

Comment: @obscure in EE sometimes it goes to disabled